# ResGen.exe not supported on .NET Core MSBuild

Tags: c#, winforms

Не подскажете в чем может быть проблема?
Я искал решения в интернете, однако такой проблемы не нашел.
В интернете в основном проблема в том, что компилятор не может найти путь к `ResGen.exe`.
У меня же пишет, что она не умеет работать с `.NET Core`.

Ссылка на библиотеку (там же проект SMBServer):
https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary

##### Фотографии

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

##### Ответ компилятора

```
Build with surface heuristics started at 15:07:36
Use build tool: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\MSBuild.dll
CONSOLE: MSBuild version 17.6.8+c70978d4d for .NET
CONSOLE: Сборка начата 31.07.2023 15:07:36.
CONSOLE: Проект "C:\Users\den\AppData\Local\Temp\Kokebof.proj" в узле 1 (целевые объекты по умолчанию).
CONSOLE: ControllerTarget:
CONSOLE:   Run controller from C:\Program Files\JetBrains\Rider\r2r\2023.1.3R\FA73FA57630A17B46C981DCEA97C9BB\JetBrains.Platform.MsBuildTask.v17.dll
2>------- Started building project: SMBServer
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3312,5): Error  : ResGen.exe not supported on .NET Core MSBuild
2>SMBServer -> D:\source\CSharp\SMBLibrary\SMBServer\bin\Debug\net40\SMBServer.exe
2>SMBServer -> D:\source\CSharp\SMBLibrary\SMBServer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SMBServer.dll
2>------- Finished building project: SMBServer. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0
Build completed in 00:00:04.811
Build failed at 15:07:41
```

---

При чем этот проект я скачивал давно еще, и компилятор не на что не ругается.
Он спокойно компилирует проект и запускает его,
Однако новый клонированный проект скачанный только что - не хочет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может ли быть версия компилятора проблемой?
Потому что на прошлой версии, которая запускается нормально стоит `c# 8.0`?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему не стоит вставлять скринШот, есть ответ обширный https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/12120#12120

Comment: ваши фотографии в виде ссылок с гитхаба, и не увеличиваются. В любом случе лучше ставить сами ошибки в виде кода, чтоб можно было прочитать/скопировать ошибку. Первая "фотография" вообще не кликабельная... я зашла, чтоб подправить думала может ошибка там в вопросе с форматированием, а у вас там ссылки гитхаб